# window.close not working on closing a tab in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I an having a issue when, After the SingleSignOn authentication completed successfully and redirect URL tab trying to close using JavaScript window.close it is not working.

I tried many JavaScript commands but nothing works for me. After analysis I got to know the redirect tab is not opening with JavaScript command because of that window.close() and other commands not working and giving the warning in console '**Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.'**

Below are some commands I have tried

```
window.open('', '\_self', '');
window.close();
```

```
publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithTenantId(tenantId).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).Build();

Dim options As SystemWebViewOptions = New SystemWebViewOptions() With { .HtmlMessageError = "<p> An error occurred: {0}. Details {1}</p>", .BrowserRedirectSuccess = New Uri("http://localhost:52655/default.aspx") } 

Dim test = publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithSystemWebViewOptions(options).ExecuteAsync().Result
```

Authentication tab is triggering from above code.

I tried commands to close the tab.
Below are some commands I have tried `window.open('', '_self', '');` `window.close();`
I noticed that window.opener is null.
Because of that all the tab close related command not working.

Comment: if you found an answer could you mark it?

Comment: I was facing issue with this approche then I have modified my code with a different approach that's work for me. I use confientialApplicationBuilder to get the authentication token

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your JavaScript code, but have you tried storing a reference in JS to the window you opened and then closing it via that handle? This code has worked when I tested it.

```js
function createPopup(url, name)
{
    // newTab will be null if window creation failed
    let newTab = window.open(url,name,'width=560,height=340,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0')
    
    if (window.focus) {
        newTab.focus()
    }

    return newTab
}

window.onload = () => {
    let win = createPopup("google window", "www.google.com")
    setTimeout(() => {
        win.close()
    }, 1000)
}
```

(I don't think StackOverflow allows snippets to open popups but you get the idea)